# Node.JS run other node.js script and php script

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

i'm tring to make manage other nodejs and php scripts on nodejs main script.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var option = { maxBuffer: 18446744073709551616 };

function Step_1(){
     exec("node /home/profile/step1.js",option,Step_2);
}
function Step_2(){
     exec("/usr/local/php/bin/php /home/profile/step2.php",option,Complete_ALL_WORK);
}
```

this is my code for run step1 and callback to step2.
but this code doesn't work. how do i run scrips on server and show output?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you see any errors?

Comment: @Passerby Nope, it doesn't show any errors but it doesn't excute the scripts.

Comment: Try to check the first parameter of `Step_2` and see if there's something wrong -- according to [official doc](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), the first parameter will be the error information (if any).